# Reference - measures in $\smash{\dot{H}}^{-1}$ have zero mean

Tags: reference-request, sobolev-spaces

The following fact seems to be well-known and easy to prove: Let $\sigma$ be a Borel measure on a Borel set $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$, then
$$\|\sigma \|_{\smash{\dot{H}}^{-1}}:\,=\sup\limits_{\|f\|_{\smash{\dot{H}}^1}\leq 1} |\langle\sigma ,f\rangle| < \infty \, \Rightarrow  \sigma (\Omega )=0 \, ,$$
where $\|f\|_{\smash{\dot{H}}^1}:\,=\|\nabla f\|_2$, and the inner product is just the integral of the product.

However, I couldn't find a proper reference in standard Sobolev Spaces textbooks (I tried Adams & Fournier and Leoni). Is this wrong? Does anyone know a solid reference?

([cross posted from MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3309539/161591) after a week with no answer).

Comment: This seems completely trivial: since $\|\cdot\|_{\dot{H}^1}$ is only a seminorm and $\|1\|_{\dot{H}^1} = 0$, then it follows immediately from the definition that in order to have $\|\sigma\|_{\dot{H}^{-1}} < \infty$ we must have $\langle \sigma, 1 \rangle = 0$.  If it's that simple, I wouldn't think any reference should be needed.

Comment: I agree it's not too hard, but a reference would be helpful for my readers.

Comment: @AmirSagiv, you might have not noticed, but your profile picture does not get displayed correctly.

Comment: Thanks @AlexM. But It looks right to me. What's the issue?

Comment: @AmirSagiv: Instead of your profile image, I see a "broken file icon" image, identical to the one displayed in [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45537897/website-icon-rel-icon-not-appearing-in-chrome-for-android). If, on the other hand, I right click on it and choose "View image", then your correct image gets displayed. I don't understand. I shall probably ask about it on Meta.

Comment: @AmirSagiv: Just for your information: setting "Content Blocking" (in Firefox 69.0) to "Standard" instead of "Strict" allows the image to be displayed correctly. I shall signal this problem on Meta.